# Installer stuck

Tags: system-installation

I used the windows installer, restarted the laptop, and choose to start Ubuntu. It's going through the installer, but is currently stuck on something And it keeps repeating that. Is there anyway to skip that and keep going?

Edit: looks like my computer froze.. So I don't have to worry about it until next try..

Comment: What laptop modal do you have?  And did you download `AMD64` or `i386`?

Comment: Hp pavilion dv6. I don't have amd64 or i386. I just used the windows installer

Comment: Is that something I should get before I try again?

Comment: Try booting with `nomodeset` - freezing is often caused by nvidia or radeon cards. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: After restarting and trying again it works. But thanks, that might be useful if I run into freezing problems latet